# Spring stateless Rest web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, stateless

I have **Spring 3** based web application. I have used `@ResponseBody` over controller for exposing some rest service to be used by web pages using ajax call.

I want to expose some stateless REST services for customer eg search, add. I have bypassed those urls and applied security on it.

It is using **Dispatcher servlet** which is being used by my web application. And it has **session timeout** of `60 minutes`. I think it will create a session for every **REST** call using existing configuration.

**Question:** How to avoid these sessions?

Thank you

Comment: And why do you think a session is created? If you don't do `request.getSession()` nothing is going to be created. The fact that there is a timeout configured doesn't mean a session is getting created...

Comment: You mean I don't have to worry for the session in my rest call. Thank you

Comment: If nothing in your code is forcing session creation no you don't...

Comment: And if I have spring session bean for storing user data in my web application. Will it cause any problem?

Comment: That depends if it is used or not

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Let me check if it is being created or not.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thank you for the explanation. Can you please convert your comments into answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there is nothing in your application forcing session creation, i.e. calls to `request.getSession` or the use of session scoped beans in controllers used by the REST calls, no sessions will be created.

The `session-timeout` is only there to state that sessions that do get created are cleaned after ~60 minutes of inactivity.